# Firebase fetches role-based documents

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

If I have a collection in firebase with several documents inside and each document has a field called for example "role", is it possible to show a user only the documents that belong to him when the whole collection is fetched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do this.

Let's assume the user has the role 'student', you can fetch all documents `.where('role', isEqualTo: 'student')`.

NB: role could also be the userId (and you can fetch all documents where role is userId).

You can use the following firebase rules to prevent unauthorised
access.

```
match /document/{docs=**} {
  allow write, read: if isAllowed();
}
function isAllowed() {
  // request.resource.data is the data being fetched.
  return request.resource.data.role == 'student';
}
function userRole() {
  // returns the user role. Use this if the user role is stored in a document.
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.role;
}
```

NB: your query must contain `.where('role', isEqualTo: 'student')` if not it will fail with insufficient permissions.

Comment: but I would like to handle it server side with firebase rules, not client side with queries.  I need to be sure that a user with a certain role only reads the documents that belong to him.

Comment: Checkout my updated answer. With the firebase rules, unauthorised access should be stopped.